# Instruction error executing UpdateMetadataAccountV2 instruction

Tags: metaplex, metadata

I'm trying to update metadataAccount of an NFT. I'm using a web interface with Phantom Wallet.

Everything works fine, until when I approve the transaction I got this error

```
{
  code: -32003,
  message: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x2d
}
```

Depending on Phantom Errors: https://docs.phantom.app/integrating/errors
This error is "Phantom does not recognize a valid transaction"

```
import { Connection, clusterApiUrl, PublicKey, Transaction } from '@solana/web3.js';
import { createUpdateMetadataAccountV2Instruction } from '@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata';
import store from './store';
const { wallet, sendTransaction } = useWallet();

const { nft } = store; // Metaplex NFT object.

const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl(cluster), 'finalized');

const accounts = {
  metadata: nft.metadataAccount.publicKey,
  updateAuthority: wallet.publicKey,
}

const args = {
  updateMetadataAccountArgsV2: {
    data: {
      name: 'XX',
      symbol: 'XX',
      uri: 'xxx',
      sellerFeeBasisPoints: 10,
      creators: [
        { address: new PublicKey("Hs7dqix1uH3e34uPhxD2gGHP1qDU5kq9Jokbo42GYcx8"), shares: 0, verified: true },
        { address: new PublicKey("6gcCoH2utP8to4i7FpkYyfhiGFRQ98cernumtkNGXLsz"), shares: 100, verified: false },
      ],
      collection: {
        key: new PublicKey('FzhgLSpK4nFYef59Wwx124QXoiqVgDTzMXT8T2DVYvns'),
        verified: false,
      },
      uses: {
        remaining: 1,
        total: 1,
        useMethod: 0
      }
    },
    updateAuthority: new PublicKey(new_authority), // new_autority from an input
    primarySaleHappened: true,
    isMutable: true,
  }
}

const updateMetadataAccount = createUpdateMetadataAccountV2Instruction(
  accounts,
  args
);

const transaction = new Transaction();
transaction.add(updateMetadataAccount);
const trx = await sendTransaction(transaction, connection);
console.log(trx);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case error code 0x2d its a Token Metadata custom error that means `ShareTotalMustBe100: Share total must equal 100 for creator array` (You can check a list of errors and the meaning of those errors [here](https://github.com/samuelvanderwaal/wtf-is/blob/main/src/errors.rs#L49)).

In your case the error is appearing because when you are setting the creator array you are providing a `shares` field instead of a `share` field, so you have to change this:

```
creators: [
        { address: new PublicKey("Hs7dqix1uH3e34uPhxD2gGHP1qDU5kq9Jokbo42GYcx8"), shares: 0, verified: true },
        { address: new PublicKey("6gcCoH2utP8to4i7FpkYyfhiGFRQ98cernumtkNGXLsz"), shares: 100, verified: false },
      ],
```

to this:

```
creators: [
        { address: new PublicKey("Hs7dqix1uH3e34uPhxD2gGHP1qDU5kq9Jokbo42GYcx8"), share: 0, verified: true },
        { address: new PublicKey("6gcCoH2utP8to4i7FpkYyfhiGFRQ98cernumtkNGXLsz"), share: 100, verified: false },
      ],
```

and that should fix the 0x2d error.

Comment: can you update this answer to clarify that 0x2d is a Token Metadata custom error _in this case_?  any program can potentially have an error code 0x2s custom error

Comment: @trent.sol done! and yeah this is completly true